# 2 different not shared databases for the same microservice good approach?

Tags: sql, nosql, microservices, domain-driven-design, cqrs

Context:
Microservices architecture, DDD, CQRS, Event driven.
SQL database.

I have an use case, where I have to store a record when a entity state is updated. I'm afraid that the quantity of records could be huge, and I was thinking that maybe an sql table is not the right place to store it. Also this records are used every now and then, and probably not by the service domain.

Could be a good practice to store it in another database(firestore, mongo, cassandra...) so it doesn't affect the performance and the scope of this service?

Thanks!

Comment: A microservice can have many databases. These databases, though, belong to the µs and are not shared with another µs.

Answer (score 1):

> Could be a good practice to store it in another database(firestore, mongo, cassandra...) so it doesn't affect the performance and the scope of this service?

Part of the benefit of using microservices is that you are hiding implementation details. As such, you are able to store/process data by whatever means is required or available without the need to broadcast that implementation to external services.

That said, from a technical standpoint, it is worth considering transaction boundaries. When writing to a single database, it is possible to commit transactions easily. Once you are writing to different databases within the same transaction, you can run into situations where one write might succeed while another one might fail.

My recommendation is to make sure you write to only one of those databases at a time. Use a two-phase commit to ensure that the second database is written to. In this way, you can avoid lost data and get the benefit of using a more efficient data store.